# Squid delaypool configuration

Tags: proxy, squid, proxy-server

i am trying to set up bandwidth limit in squid (Windows Port), but when i use delaypools i am getting error messages like this,

> 2013/01/22 10:05:06| parseConfigFile: squid.conf:151 unrecognized:
>   'delay_pools'
>
> 2013/01/22 10:05:06| parseConfigFile: squid.conf:152 unrecognized:
>   'delay_calss'
>
> 2013/01/22 10:05:06| parseConfigFile: squid.conf:153 unrecognized:
>   'delay_parame ters' 2013/01/22 10:05:06| parseConfigFile:
>   squid.conf:154 unrecognized: 'delay_access '

How can i fix it ?